# SpringDataNeo4j-4 derived finders with custom queries

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I am currently using SpringDataNeo4j–4.1.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT. I access the database using the “extends GraphRepository" structure and the Neo4jTemplate. Among other things I am using simple derived finder queries like:

```
Event findById (Long id)
```

This works fine and returns results as expected. Now I have cases where I want to find an entry by property but only retrieve certain relationships:

```
@Query("MATCH (n:Event{dbId:{0}})-[r:species|figure]->(m) RETURN n,r,m")
Event findById (Long id)
```

I know this is right now not supported. Is there a possible workaround for this behaviour without having to construct the object on my own and will this be implemented in the future versions of SDN since OGM 2.0.0-M01 now offers the possibility perform queries like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Neo4jTemplate.query` and retrieve "n" from the `Result`.

n will be an `Event` that's been hydrated with properties and relationships for `species` and 'figure`.

Or, you can instead create a `@QueryResult` that the repository method annotated with the custom `Query` returns, and you'll still get back the hydrated Event.

This functionality is already available in the SDN 4.1 snapshot (4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT)

Your query above

`@Query("MATCH (n:Event{dbId:{0}})-[r:species|figure]->(m) RETURN Return n,r,m")
Event findById (Long id)`

is not supported because there are three entities returned by the query, but only a single one expected to be returned.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, but I am not sure understand what you mean. I have already tried to use template.query: 
Nevertheless this will basically return a table that I have to map myself. I have also tried template.queryForObject but this will only return Event without the populated by the relationships.

Comment: Neo4jTemplate.query should return the Result object which contains mapped entities (it just delegates to session.query) Are you sure it's using OGM 2.0?

Comment: Yes I am positive on using OGM-2.0.0-M01. I have tried:  

`String query = "MATCH (n:Event{dbId:{dbId}})-[r:species|figure]->(m) RETURN n";
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("dbId",549475);
Result result =  neo4jTemplate.query(query,map);`  
The result will be a list of HashMaps containing my events. But since I only return n the list contains basically the same object multiple times without my relationships. If I return n and m the result will have one more “column” but I dont see automatic mapping.

Comment: Oh you can't return just n. The OGM will map only what is returned. So please return n,r,m and then inspect n to see if it references m as expected.

Comment: Ahh now I get it Result will still mimic a table format, but because of the smartObjectMapping n will now be populated.
I was a little confused because of the format of Result. Thank you!